# Is using a float[] array or 16 floats better with respect to memory usage?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, floating-point, garbage-collection

I have the following `Matrix4f` class:

```
public class Matrix4f {
    private final static float EPSILON = 0.01f;

    private final static Matrix4f IDENTITY = new Matrix4f(new float[] {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //X column
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //Y column
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //Z column
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  //W column
    });

    private final float[] elements = new float[16];

    public Matrix4f() {

    }

    public Matrix4f(final float[] elements) {
        System.arraycopy(elements, 0, this.elements, 0, 16);
    }

    public Matrix4f multiply(final Matrix4f other) {
        float[] a = getElements();
        float[] b = other.getElements();
        return new Matrix4f(new float[] {
            a[0] * b[0] +   a[4] * b[1] +   a[8] * b[2] +   a[12] * b[3],
            a[1] * b[0] +   a[5] * b[1] +   a[9] * b[2] +   a[13] * b[3],
            a[2] * b[0] +   a[6] * b[1] +   a[10] * b[2] +  a[14] * b[3],
            a[3] * b[0] +   a[7] * b[1] +   a[11] * b[2] +  a[15] * b[3],   //X column

            a[0] * b[4] +   a[4] * b[5] +   a[8] * b[6] +   a[12] * b[7],
            a[1] * b[4] +   a[5] * b[5] +   a[9] * b[6] +   a[13] * b[7],
            a[2] * b[4] +   a[6] * b[5] +   a[10] * b[6] +  a[14] * b[7],
            a[3] * b[4] +   a[7] * b[5] +   a[11] * b[6] +  a[15] * b[7],   //Y column

            a[0] * b[8] +   a[4] * b[9] +   a[8] * b[10] +  a[12] * b[11],
            a[1] * b[8] +   a[5] * b[9] +   a[9] * b[10] +  a[13] * b[11],
            a[2] * b[8] +   a[6] * b[9] +   a[10] * b[10] + a[14] * b[11],
            a[3] * b[8] +   a[7] * b[9] +   a[11] * b[10] + a[15] * b[11],  //Z column

            a[0] * b[12] +  a[4] * b[13] +  a[8] * b[14] +  a[12] * b[15],
            a[1] * b[12] +  a[5] * b[13] +  a[9] * b[14] +  a[13] * b[15],
            a[2] * b[12] +  a[6] * b[13] +  a[10] * b[14] + a[14] * b[15],
            a[3] * b[12] +  a[7] * b[13] +  a[11] * b[14] + a[15] * b[15]  //W column            
        });
    }

    public FloatBuffer asFloatBuffer() {
        FloatBuffer floatBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(elements.length).put(elements);
        floatBuffer.flip();
        return floatBuffer;
    }

    public FloatBuffer writeToFloatBuffer(final FloatBuffer floatBuffer) {
        floatBuffer.clear();
        floatBuffer.put(elements);
        floatBuffer.flip();
        return floatBuffer;
    }

    float[] getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(elements);
    }

    public static Matrix4f identity() {
        return IDENTITY;
    }

    public static Matrix4f scale(final float sx, final float sy, final float sz) {
        return new Matrix4f(new float[] {
            sx, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   //X column
            0.0f, sy, 0.0f, 0.0f,   //Y column
            0.0f, 0.0f, sz, 0.0f,   //Z column
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  //W column
        });
    }

    public static Matrix4f translate(final float tx, final float ty, final float tz) {
        return new Matrix4f(new float[] {
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //X column
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //Y column
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //Z column
            tx,    ty,    tz, 1.0f  //W column
        });
    }

    public static Matrix4f rotate(final float theta, final float x, final float y, final float z) {
        if (Math.abs(x * x + y * y + z * z - 1.0f) >= EPSILON) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("(x, y, z) is not a unit vector: x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", z = " + z);
        }
        float thetaRad = (float)Math.toRadians(theta);
        float cosTheta = (float)Math.cos(thetaRad);
        float sinTheta = (float)Math.sin(thetaRad);
        float cosThetaRes = 1.0f - cosTheta;
        return new Matrix4f(new float[] {
            cosTheta + x * x * cosThetaRes,     y * x * cosThetaRes + z * sinTheta, z * x * cosThetaRes - y * sinTheta, 0.0f,   //X column
            x * y * cosThetaRes - z * sinTheta, cosTheta + y * y * cosThetaRes,     z * y * cosThetaRes + x * sinTheta, 0.0f,   //Y column
            x * z * cosThetaRes + y * sinTheta, y * z * cosThetaRes - x * sinTheta, cosTheta + z * z * cosThetaRes,     0.0f,   //Z column
            0.0f,                               0.0f,                               0.0f,                               1.0f    //W column
        });
    }

    public static Matrix4f frustum(final float left, final float right, final float bottom, final float top, final float near, final float far) {
        return new Matrix4f(new float[] {
            2 * near / (right - left),          0.0f,                               0.0f,                           0.0f,   //X column
            0.0f,                               2 * near / (top - bottom),          0.0f,                           0.0f,   //Y column
            (right + left) / (right - left),    (top + bottom) / (top - bottom),    (near + far) / (near - far),    -1.0f,  //Z column
            0.0f,                               0.0f,                               2 * near * far / (near - far),  0.0f    //Z column
        });
    }

    public static Matrix4f perspective(final float fovy, final float aspect, final float near, final float far) {
        float y2 = near * (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fovy * 0.5f));
        float y1 = -y2;
        float x1 = y1 * aspect;
        float x2 = y2 * aspect;
        return frustum(x1, x2, y1, y2, near, far);
    }

    public static Matrix4f multiply(final Matrix4f... matrices) {
        Matrix4f output = identity();
        for (Matrix4f matrix : matrices) {
            output = output.multiply(matrix);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

When profiling my 3D application practically everything is being correct, except that an abnormal high amount of `float[]`s are being made. This could be normal behaviour as lots of matrix multiplications are being done.

Would there however be a significant improvement in performance (and on what reasons) if I were to change it to use 16 `float`s instead of one `float[]`?

I optimized the following part (below) a few minutes ago, and it gave me a huge performance increase:

```
public FloatBuffer asFloatBuffer() {
    FloatBuffer floatBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(elements.length).put(elements);
    floatBuffer.flip();
    return floatBuffer;
}

public FloatBuffer writeToFloatBuffer(final FloatBuffer floatBuffer) {
    floatBuffer.clear();
    floatBuffer.put(elements);
    floatBuffer.flip();
    return floatBuffer;
}
```

What I effectively did there was getting rid of the `new` instances, would a similar thing work with the floats and **why**?

**UPDATED:** I made a new version, and it has definately shown it's improvements! I used to be able to draw 240 times which in turn caused stutter every second because of the garbage collection overhead. Now I can draw 24000 times with methods that create no garbage at all, now the actual limiting factor is most likely that I am just doing too many OpenGL calls or osmething, which is not an issue, as I should search other means if I were to send that much data to OpenGL in a real scenario.

The updated code:

```
@Override
protected void render(final double msDelta) {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepthf(1f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    testProgram.use();

    FloatBuffer modelViewMatrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    Matrix4f modelviewMatrix = new Matrix4f();

    for (int i = 0; i < 24000; i++) {
        float fVar = i + currentTime / 1000f * 0.3f;
        modelviewMatrix.identity()
                .translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -8.0f)   //translate
                .rotate(currentTime / 1000f * 45.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)  //rotate around Y
                .rotate(currentTime / 1000f * 21.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)  //rotate around X
                .translate(
                    (float)Math.sin(2.1f * fVar) * 2.0f,
                    (float)Math.cos(1.7f * fVar) * 2.0f,
                    (float)Math.sin(1.3f * fVar) * (float)Math.cos(1.5f * fVar) * 2.0f
                );  //translate
        glUniformMatrix4(MODELVIEW_LOCATION, false, modelviewMatrix.writeToFloatBuffer(modelViewMatrixBuffer));    
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Matrix4f {
    private final static float EPSILON = 0.01f;    
    private final static int LENGTH = 16;

    private float elem0 = 0.0f, elem1 = 0.0f, elem2 = 0.0f, elem3 = 0.0f,
            elem4 = 0.0f, elem5 = 0.0f, elem6 = 0.0f, elem7 = 0.0f,
            elem8 = 0.0f, elem9 = 0.0f, elem10 = 0.0f, elem11 = 0.0f,
            elem12 = 0.0f, elem13 = 0.0f, elem14 = 0.0f, elem15 = 0.0f;

    public Matrix4f() {

    }

    public Matrix4f(final float elem0, final float elem1, final float elem2, final float elem3,
            final float elem4, final float elem5, final float elem6, final float elem7,
            final float elem8, final float elem9, final float elem10, final float elem11, 
            final float elem12, final float elem13, final float elem14, final float elem15) {
        set(elem0, elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4, elem5, elem6, elem7, elem8, elem9, elem10, elem11, elem12, elem13, elem14, elem15);
    }

    public Matrix4f identity() {
        set(
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //X column
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //Y column
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //Z column
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f   //W column
        );
        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f multiply(final Matrix4f other) {
        return multiply(
            other.elem0, other.elem1, other.elem2, other.elem3, 
            other.elem4, other.elem5, other.elem6, other.elem7, 
            other.elem8, other.elem9, other.elem10, other.elem11, 
            other.elem12, other.elem13, other.elem14, other.elem15
        );
    }

    public Matrix4f multiply(final float mul0, final float mul1, final float mul2, final float mul3,
            final float mul4, final float mul5, final float mul6, final float mul7,
            final float mul8, final float mul9, final float mul10, final float mul11,
            final float mul12, final float mul13, final float mul14, final float mul15) {
        set(
            this.elem0 * mul0 +   this.elem4 * mul1 +   this.elem8 * mul2 +   this.elem12 * mul3,
            this.elem1 * mul0 +   this.elem5 * mul1 +   this.elem9 * mul2 +   this.elem13 * mul3,
            this.elem2 * mul0 +   this.elem6 * mul1 +   this.elem10 * mul2 +  this.elem14 * mul3,
            this.elem3 * mul0 +   this.elem7 * mul1 +   this.elem11 * mul2 +  this.elem15 * mul3,   //X column

            this.elem0 * mul4 +   this.elem4 * mul5 +   this.elem8 * mul6 +   this.elem12 * mul7,
            this.elem1 * mul4 +   this.elem5 * mul5 +   this.elem9 * mul6 +   this.elem13 * mul7,
            this.elem2 * mul4 +   this.elem6 * mul5 +   this.elem10 * mul6 +  this.elem14 * mul7,
            this.elem3 * mul4 +   this.elem7 * mul5 +   this.elem11 * mul6 +  this.elem15 * mul7,   //Y column

            this.elem0 * mul8 +   this.elem4 * mul9 +   this.elem8 * mul10 +  this.elem12 * mul11,
            this.elem1 * mul8 +   this.elem5 * mul9 +   this.elem9 * mul10 +  this.elem13 * mul11,
            this.elem2 * mul8 +   this.elem6 * mul9 +   this.elem10 * mul10 + this.elem14 * mul11,
            this.elem3 * mul8 +   this.elem7 * mul9 +   this.elem11 * mul10 + this.elem15 * mul11,  //Z column

            this.elem0 * mul12 +  this.elem4 * mul13 +  this.elem8 * mul14 +  this.elem12 * mul15,
            this.elem1 * mul12 +  this.elem5 * mul13 +  this.elem9 * mul14 +  this.elem13 * mul15,
            this.elem2 * mul12 +  this.elem6 * mul13 +  this.elem10 * mul14 + this.elem14 * mul15,
            this.elem3 * mul12 +  this.elem7 * mul13 +  this.elem11 * mul14 + this.elem15 * mul15  //W column            
        );
        return this;
    }

    public Matrix4f scale(final float sx, final float sy, final float sz) {
        return multiply(
            sx, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   //X column
            0.0f, sy, 0.0f, 0.0f,   //Y column
            0.0f, 0.0f, sz, 0.0f,   //Z column
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  //W column
        );
    }

    public Matrix4f translate(final float tx, final float ty, final float tz) {
        return multiply(
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //X column
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //Y column
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, //Z column
            tx,    ty,    tz, 1.0f  //W column
        );
    }

    public Matrix4f rotate(final float theta, final float x, final float y, final float z) {
        if (Math.abs(x * x + y * y + z * z - 1.0f) >= EPSILON) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("(x, y, z) is not a unit vector: x = " + x + ", y = " + y + ", z = " + z);
        }
        float thetaRad = (float)Math.toRadians(theta);
        float cosTheta = (float)Math.cos(thetaRad);
        float sinTheta = (float)Math.sin(thetaRad);
        float cosThetaRes = 1.0f - cosTheta;
        return multiply(
            cosTheta + x * x * cosThetaRes,     y * x * cosThetaRes + z * sinTheta, z * x * cosThetaRes - y * sinTheta, 0.0f,   //X column
            x * y * cosThetaRes - z * sinTheta, cosTheta + y * y * cosThetaRes,     z * y * cosThetaRes + x * sinTheta, 0.0f,   //Y column
            x * z * cosThetaRes + y * sinTheta, y * z * cosThetaRes - x * sinTheta, cosTheta + z * z * cosThetaRes,     0.0f,   //Z column
            0.0f,                               0.0f,                               0.0f,                               1.0f    //W column
        );
    }

    public Matrix4f frustum(final float left, final float right, final float bottom, final float top, final float near, final float far) {
        return multiply(
            2 * near / (right - left),          0.0f,                               0.0f,                           0.0f,   //X column
            0.0f,                               2 * near / (top - bottom),          0.0f,                           0.0f,   //Y column
            (right + left) / (right - left),    (top + bottom) / (top - bottom),    (near + far) / (near - far),    -1.0f,  //Z column
            0.0f,                               0.0f,                               2 * near * far / (near - far),  0.0f    //Z column
        );
    }

    public Matrix4f perspective(final float fovy, final float aspect, final float near, final float far) {
        float y2 = near * (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fovy * 0.5f));
        float y1 = -y2;
        float x1 = y1 * aspect;
        float x2 = y2 * aspect;
        return frustum(x1, x2, y1, y2, near, far);
    }

    public FloatBuffer asFloatBuffer() {
        FloatBuffer floatBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(LENGTH)
                .put(elem0).put(elem1).put(elem2).put(elem3)
                .put(elem4).put(elem5).put(elem6).put(elem7)
                .put(elem8).put(elem9).put(elem10).put(elem11)
                .put(elem12).put(elem13).put(elem14).put(elem15);
        floatBuffer.flip();
        return floatBuffer;
    }

    public FloatBuffer writeToFloatBuffer(final FloatBuffer floatBuffer) {
        floatBuffer.clear();
        floatBuffer.put(elem0).put(elem1).put(elem2).put(elem3)
                .put(elem4).put(elem5).put(elem6).put(elem7)
                .put(elem8).put(elem9).put(elem10).put(elem11)
                .put(elem12).put(elem13).put(elem14).put(elem15);
        floatBuffer.flip();
        return floatBuffer;
    }

    private void set(final float elem0, final float elem1, final float elem2, final float elem3,
            final float elem4, final float elem5, final float elem6, final float elem7,
            final float elem8, final float elem9, final float elem10, final float elem11, 
            final float elem12, final float elem13, final float elem14, final float elem15) {
        this.elem0 = elem0;
        this.elem1 = elem1;
        this.elem2 = elem2;
        this.elem3 = elem3;
        this.elem4 = elem4;
        this.elem5 = elem5;
        this.elem6 = elem6;
        this.elem7 = elem7;
        this.elem8 = elem8;
        this.elem9 = elem9;
        this.elem10 = elem10;
        this.elem11 = elem11;
        this.elem12 = elem12;
        this.elem13 = elem13;
        this.elem14 = elem14;
        this.elem15 = elem15;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + 
                elem0 + ", "  + elem1 + ", "  + elem2 + ", "  + elem3 + ", " +
                elem4 + ", "  + elem5 + ", "  + elem6 + ", "  + elem7 + ", " +
                elem8 + ", "  + elem9 + ", "  + elem10 + ", " + elem11 + ", " +
                elem12 + ", " + elem13 + ", " + elem14 + ", " + elem15 + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Those float values would still take 4 bytes each. Constants won't help here as primitives vaules are always copied - don't be confused with objects that are using references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in java are classes! -> so they are created in the heap and subdue to GC - one of the biggest performance killers (because they freeze the application until the GC is complete). The less allocations you make - the better! Also as calsses they have additional memory overhead:

> Each Java object has a header that contains information important for the JVM. The most important is a reference to the object's class (one machine word), and there are some flags used by the garbage collector and to manage synchronization (since every object can be synchronized on) which takes up another machine word (using partial words would be bad for performance). So that's 2 words, which is 8 bytes on 32 bit systems, and 16 bytes on 64 bit. Arrays additionally need an int field for the array length, which is another 4 bytes, possibly 8 on 64 bit systems.

Source: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162546/why-the-overhead-when-allocating-objects-arrays-in-java

PS: Just a side note - run your app using `-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis` - this might reduce the number of allocations even more

Comment: With modern JVMs GC is much less of an issue, short lived objects are tidied up as they are created and discarded without needing a full GC.

Comment: @TimB It is still a big enough issue to be worth investigating. In the perfect world everything would consist out of Objects for sake of readability/clarify (well... maybe not everything), but this matters a lot in terms of performance. I have learnt that having data on the stack should always be preferred over the heap in high performance applications (3D for example).

Answer (score 1):

Using 16 floats instead of an array will save you ~16 bytes. A fixed number of local variables can also help you avoid creating new objects.  e.g. you could use mutable matricies and avoid creating a new object.

```
public Matrix multiply(Matrix m) {
    float a11 = this.a11;
    // etc
    float a44 = this.a44;

    this.a11 = ...;
    // etc
    this.a44 = ...;
}
```

Note: this operation creates no garbage at all.

Comment: So manipulating the current matrix in all methods, instead of returning a new `Matrix4f` is using a better way of doing it?

Comment: @skiwi better if you don't need a new Matrix. It avoids creating new objects.

Comment: However be aware that there are good reasons for using immutable objects in some places. There are performance costs from the object creation but a lot of the time they are worthwhile.

Comment: @TimB It's one of those *premature optimization is evil* cases, basically you want to be dealing with objects, else I would've written it in other languages I guess.

Comment: @skiwi: Sometimes it's best to create both mutable and immutable types. You get the best of both worlds and often it's only a slightly more work (for example, you can implement matrix addition `a + b` as `c = a.clone(); c += b;`). So it may be no premature optimization, as you get more functionality, too (immutability is cool but sometimes it's a pain).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't see why you need to instantiate the `Matrix4f` class for every matrix.  You could just operate directly on the `float[]` objects, and save yourself one allocation for each one.  This will save you 8 bytes per matrix (possibly 16 bytes on 64-bit systems, I'm not sure).  This is not a big deal, but since those 8 bytes don't buy you anything, I think it would be worth doing.

Secondly, I'm guessing that whenever you want to translate, rotate or scale something, you're calling the method that creates the appropriate transformation matrix, then multiplying it by the matrix that represents the thing that you're transforming.

That seems wasteful to me, because

- you allocate two arrays - one of which you're going to throw away immediately
- you do a lot of multiplying things by `1.0` or `0.0`, and adding up results.  So you do a lot of arithmetic for nothing.

I would rewrite your `translate`, `rotate` and `scale` methods so that each of them takes an additional argument - the matrix that you want to transform, and just does the minimum amount of arithmetic, and more importantly, only one allocation.  For example

```
public static float[] scale(float sx, float sy, float sz, float[] operand) {
    float[] toReturn = new float[16];
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++){ 
        toReturn[ i ] = operand[ i ] * sx;
        toReturn[ i + 4 ] = operand[ i + 4 ] * sy;
        toReturn[ i + 8 ] = operand[ i + 8 ] * sz;
        toReturn[ i + 12 ] = operand[ i + 12 ];
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

If you don't need to keep the original matrix when you do one of these transformations, then you could make each transformation operate directly on the matrix.  This will save you two transformations, not just one.

For example, your `scale` method might look like this, in the case where you don't want to keep the original matrix.

```
public static void scale(float sx, float sy, float sz, float[] operand) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++){ 
        operand[ i ] *= sx;
        operand[ i + 4 ] *= sy;
        operand[ i + 8 ] *= sz;
    }
}
```

which just modifies the existing matrix.  This means that you get rid of two allocations of `float[]` - one for the transformation matrix, and one for the result matrix.

If you need to keep the original matrix, then you could write it in a way that creates the result matrix, but not the transformation matrix; so you'll halve the number of allocations.

Comment: Correct, earlier today I had the idea that the garbage collector was more powerful, ie. it would be able to collect everything created in a method 'immediatly' (well... once it runs), but I know better now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, arrays in Java are represented as Objects. You can test it yourself:

```
private final float[] elements = new float[16];

if (elements instanceof Object){ 
   System.out.println("Array are Objects!")
}
```

So in term of memory you should get a benefit, even if I'm not sure how much. I'm curios abou it so if you find out please share :)

Comment: I doubt that there will be any significant benefit in switching from float array to float fields. float[] object basically is made of mark word (8 bytes) + int length field (4 bytes) + length*4 byte (as per float). With fields you will safe on those length and mark word fields, I guess.

Comment: As I wrote in my post, objects are slow because of the GC overhead they cause. The less allocations , the better. Simple floats might be allocated on the stack instead - so no GC, also they might not be allocated memory , but be used directly in register-register computations - which are even faster, because no memory have to be fetched from RAM/cache

Comment: Performance has been gone up from about 1 GB worth of `float[]` every few seconds, to none.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question regarding big amount of float[] instances on your heap.

It seems to me you are experiencing one of the following two issues: either you are creating too many instances of Matrix4f classes that are in real use (have live references) or some of the instances are not garbage collected when they should be.

The second could turn out to be a big problem. It seems to me that there are no obstacles to make Matrix4f immutable - which it's now not, due to `elements` array escaping the class in `getElements()` since array are ***always mutable*** plus some code could get a reference on that float[] and never gave it up resulting in heap pollution. My advice would be to either remove this method if you don't need it or return a copy of the array if you really need this ***or*** provide an accessor method using row and col.

Using float fields instead of float array should reduce the number of allocations (those of float[]) but the heap could still be polluted with Matrix4f instances so be careful.

Note that elements array is also escaping in asFloatBuffer method. So again I would think of eliminating this entirely or using a copy - that way at least Matrix4f objects will be GCed.

As for performance I would first check for duplicated calculations, like `x*cosThetaRes` and etc that use in multiple places but always recalculate them. Another thing is to check for another algorithm that uses less operations in order to get the result, especially when you know the size. Not sure but I guess [Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) may be of help as it's relatively simple.